# GME - Difference in Turn Angle and Bearing

Tags: gme

When using the movement.pathmetrics tool in GME, I get an out put table of turn angle and bearing. Can someone clarify as to what the difference between the turn angle and the bearing field is?

Answer (score 1):

As it is described in the [**documentation**](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/movementpathmetrics.htm),

> This tool calculates turn angles, step lengths, bearings, and time
>   intervals for a point time series dataset. The turn angle is based on
>   the point sequence p(t-1), p(t), p(t+1); the step lengths, bearings
>   and time intervals are based on the sequence p(t), p(t+1). Thus, a
>   NoData value (-999) will be written for the first and last turn angles
>   in a point series, and for the last step length, bearing and time
>   interval records. These NoData values should obviously not be included
>   in subsequent analyses.

In other words, the turn angle, is essentially, the angle between path segments (sometimes referred to as sweep angle) and the bearing is the direction of the segment.